# mysql mostrar el registro que este vigente en fecha

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

Hola amigos me podrian ayudar?
Tengo estos registros:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | date_start | date_end   |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 181 | 1511553600 | 1511899200 |
| 186 | 1512158400 | 1512504000 |
| 191 | 1512763200 | 1513108800 |
| 196 | 1513368000 | 1513713600 |
| 201 | 1513715400 | 1514136600 |
| 206 | 1515340800 | 1515427200 |
| 211 | 1515945600 | 1516032000 |
| 216 | 1516550400 | 1516636800 |
| 221 | 1517155200 | 1517241600 |
| 226 | 1517760000 | 1517846400 |
| 231 | 1518364800 | 1518451200 |
| 236 | 1518969600 | 1519056000 |
| 241 | 1519574400 | 1519660800 |
| 246 | 1519833600 | 1519920000 |
| 251 | 1520179200 | 1520265600 |
| 256 | 1520784000 | 1520870400 |
| 261 | 1521388800 | 1521475200 |
| 266 | 1522594800 | 1522681200 |
| 271 | 1523199600 | 1523286000 |
| 276 | 1523804400 | 1523890800 |
| 281 | 1524063600 | 1524150000 |
| 286 | 1524409200 | 1524495600 |
| 291 | 1525014000 | 1525100400 |
| 296 | 1525618800 | 1525705200 |
| 301 | 1526223600 | 1526310000 |
| 306 | 1526828400 | 1526914800 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

Tengo la fecha iniciar y final en formato timestamp, como podria hacer una consulta para que me muestre el registro mas proximo o vigente,a la fecha actual es decir mostar el registro cuando date_start este entre now() y date_end pero tambien mostar el registro cuando now() este entre date_start y date_end.

ya que necesito siempre tener el que esta proximo o el que esta ocurriendo,

tengo estas consultas:

```
SELECT id FROM tabla1 WHERE (date_start BETWEEN unix_timestamp() AND date_end) order by id asc limit 1;
SELECT id FROM tabla1 WHERE (unix_timestamp() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) order by id asc limit 1;
```

Pero no se como unirlas para que me muestre el registro actual que es el `id 186`
me podrian ayudar porfavor

saludos

Comment: me parece que tu mismo te has contestado, solo has un between entre los campos que tienes, intenta hacer la consulta por tu cuenta con between y si no puedes entonces vienes con una duda más específica, o pega el código que llevas hecho

Comment: hola, gracias añadi la consulta arriba

Answer (score 1):

Según tu enunciado

> mostar el registro cuando date_start este entre now() y date_end pero
>   tambien mostar el registro cuando now() este entre date_start y
>   date_end.

Eso se traduce en:

> los que terminen después del presente **Y** (empiecen después de el
>   presente **O** empiecen antes del presente).

La segunda condición abarca todos los casos posibles, de manera que sólo necesitas comocer el que termina más pronto de entre los que no han terminado

```
SELECT id 
FROM tabla1 
WHERE (unix_timestamp()<date_end) 
ORDER BY date_end ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Esto suponiendo que los lapsos de tiempo no se superponen.

Comment: gracias, las fechas tiene un rango de fecha entre si de 1 o dos dias, no se superponen, muchas gracias lo probare, saludos